# Materialize Select JavaScript: Cannot initialize .formSelect not a function, .append not a function

Tags: javascript, materialize

As you can see by the comments in code snippets below, I've tried everything that seems to make sense. I find the Materialize documentation very old and lacking details and working code examples. I've found 1 or 2 posts here on SO and I'm trying (see commented code) the suggestions. I cannot make this work.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, thank you, thank you for helping :-)

Here is the Html content...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select id="collName">
                <option>( Choose collection... )</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select id="query">
                <option>( Choose query... )</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="status" class="col s12">Ready</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="collections" class="col s4">4 columns</div>
        <div id="container" class="col s8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is JavaScript code...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // const elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    // const options = {};
    // const instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);

    const optionsColls = [];
    config.collections.forEach(c => {
        optionsColls.push("<option>" + c + "</option")
    });

    const elemCollName = document.getElementById('collName');
    collName = M.FormSelect.init(elemCollName, {});
    //collName = M.FormSelect.getInstance(elemCollName);
    // collName.empty();
    collName.formSelect();
    collName.append(optionsColls);

    // config.collections.forEach(coll => {
    //  collName.options.add(new Option(coll, coll));
    // });

});
```

Comment: Well the error means simply that `"FormSelect"` does not exist as a property of the "M" object. Have you  tried doing a `console.log(M)` to verify that it's the object you think it is?  (Also note that in the question title you've written "formSelect", but in the code it's "FormSelect"; those are not the same.)

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, yes M is Materialize loaded. Sorry about the incorrect lowercase f/F part. Any other suggestions? :-)

Comment: Well wait a sec; there's the `FormSelect` object apparently, but you indeed *are* making a call to `.formSelect()`. Hmm ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying lots of different combinations of code and nothing is working as is said in other SO posts. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Well [according to the documentation](https://materializecss.com/select.html), `.formSelect()` is "old" and intended to be used with jQuery; you don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Yes I saw that. I've tried numerous variations without that line.

Comment: Also, notice the .init(elem, options) in that documentation with no example of using it. Nothing on what elem is (but I know that) and nothing about what options should be.

Answer (score 1):

The following does work when loading/init'ing the Select...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const elemCollName = document.getElementById('collName');
    config.collections.forEach(c => {
        elemCollName.options.add(new Option(c, c));
    });
    M.FormSelect.init(elemCollName);
});
```

This also seems to work fine when you're dynamically loading Select option lists in events. Just always call the .init() after you modify your Select.